# SQL/ActiveRecord nested joins query to return results only if all rows match a range

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've tried to find the answer for couple of days but haven't found it. Please advise:

For example:

1. I have `User`, `Cupboards`, `Shelf` and `Book` models in my project.
2. Above models connected with relation `:has_many` (`User`  :has_many `Cupboards`, .. , `Shelf` :has_many `Books`)
3. `Book` has property - `:color`

I need to find `Users` who have only `yellow` or `red` books.

I built such query but it returns users which have at list one yellow or red book:

```
User.joins(:cupboard => {:shelfs => :books}).where("books.color IN (?)", %w(red yellow)
```

Thanks in advance for your help guys!

Comment: Remember that a person who only has yellow or red books is also a person who doesn't have any books that are any color other than yellow or red...

Comment: "I need to find Users who have only yellow or red books" - following this, your query is ok. Maybe you need user with yellow AND red books?